# image coordinate to world coordinate opencv

Tags: opencv, camera, computer-vision, projection, camera-calibration

I calibrated my mono camera using opencv. Now I know the camera intrinsic matrix and distortion coefs [K1, K2, P1 ,P2,K3 ,K4, K5, K6] of my camera. Assuming that camera is place in [x, y, z] with [Roll, Pitch, Yaw] rotations. how can I get each pixel in world coordinate when the camera is looking on the floor [z=0].

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You say that you calibrated your camera which gives you:

- Intrinsic parameters
- Extrinsic parameters (rotation, translation)
- Distortion coefficients

First, to compensate for the distortion, you can use the [undistort](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#undistort) function and get an undistorted image. Now, what you are left with is the intrinsic/extrinsic parameters and the pinhole camera model. The equation below taken from the [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html) explains how to transform 3D world coordinates into 2D image coordinates using those parameters:

[image]

Basically, you multiply the 3D coordinates by a projection matrix, which in turn is a combination of the intrinsic parameters (the first matrix in the equation) and the extrinsic parameters (the second matrix in the equation). The extrinsic parameters matrix contains both rotation and translation components `[R|T]`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think it is the general case. It seems that transition [X, Y, Z] of the camera position should goes to t1 t2 t3. but I don't understand how can I get r11 ~ r33 from [Roll, Pitch, Yaw]. And what about my constranit that the camera is looking to the floor [Z=0]?

Comment: If you're looking to the floor, Z=0 in the equation, and the transformation becomes invertible, as described in the slide 27 of the presentation I mentioned in my answer (http://www.gris.tu-darmstadt.de/teaching/courses/ss11/cv1/l9-singleview-v1.pdf).

Comment: Regarding the values r11~r33, they form the so called rotation matrix. It can be written as R=ABC, where A, B, and C represent rotations about a different axis (the axes are chosen according to a convention). The rotation amount is given by the roll, pitch, and yaw angles, but since there are different conventions, the values of A, B, and C can vary. As a reference for implementing the conversion, you can use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerAngles.html.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you start by studying the pinhole camera model, which models the process through which a point in the 3D world is mapped to the image plane using the camera intrinsic parameters. As you'll see, this process is not one-to-one, and thus it usually cannot be inverted (image to 3D), unless you have depth information (which you have, since you said the points are located at z=0). This particular case is mentioned on slide 27 of [this presentation](http://www.gris.tu-darmstadt.de/teaching/courses/ss11/cv1/l9-singleview-v1.pdf). Previous lectures explain in details the image formation process, and can be used as a first reference to actually determine the transformation from image to world coordinates.   [Szeliski's book](http://szeliski.org/Book/drafts/SzeliskiBook_20100903_draft.pdf) and [this PDF](http://www.cim.mcgill.ca/~langer/558/4-cameramodel.pdf) are also great resources.

Comment: Unfortunately the link to the presentation does not work any more. Do you know whether the presentation is gone or was simply moved?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your camera has T=[x y x]' translation according to world reference, and as you told your camera has R=[roll, pitch yawn] rotation and your camera instrics parameter is in K. Any pixel ([px py] on image plane) has W=[X,Y] coordinate on world plane adn W can be calculated just with following Matlab code

```
R = rotationVectorToMatrix(R)'
H=K*[R T];`
Q=inv([H(:,1) H(:,2) -[px;py;1]])*-H(:,4);
W=Q(1:2)
```

Here, end of the document is good example what I mean, https://github.com/muhammetbalcilar/Stereo-Camera-Calibration-Orthogonal-Planes