# how to convert the pixel coordinates to world coordinates?

Tags: c++, computer-vision, opencv3.0, robotics

I'm working on a robotic project is that I need to detect key points get the coordinates of this points and transfer them to the robot to manipulate.
I made the camera calibration and used the calibration information to un-distort the image from my camera and then applied ORB technique to detect the key points. till now everything is good but I don't know how to map these key points coordinates to work with the robot.

Here is code I'm using:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

std::vector<KeyPoint> kp;
Mat frame;
Mat frame_un;
Mat camera_matrix =(Mat_<double>(3,3) << 7.4191833420713715e+02, 0.0, 320.0, 0.0, 7.4191833420713715e+02, 240.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    1.0);
Mat distortion_coefficients =(Mat_<double>(5,1) << -1.5271566741564191e-01, 1.5488166759164064e+00, 0.0, 0.0,
    -7.6517765981508861e+00);

VideoCapture cap(1); // open the default camera
if (!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
    return -1;

for (;;)
{

    cap.read(frame); // get a new frame from camera
    if (frame.empty()) 
continue;
undistort(frame, frame_un, camera_matrix, distortion_coefficients);
 // Default parameters of ORB
    int nfeatures=30;
    float scaleFactor=1.2f;
    int nlevels=8;
    int edgeThreshold=31; // Changed default (31);
    int firstLevel=0;
    int WTA_K=2;
    int scoreType=ORB::HARRIS_SCORE;
    int patchSize=31;
    int fastThreshold=20;

Ptr<ORB> detector = ORB::create(
    nfeatures,
    scaleFactor,
    nlevels,
    edgeThreshold,
    firstLevel,
    WTA_K,
    scoreType,
    patchSize,
    fastThreshold );

    detector->detect(frame_un, kp);
    std::cout << "Found " << kp.size() << " Keypoints " << std::endl;
for(int i=0; i<=kp.size();i++)
{ 
int x = kp[i].pt.x;
int y = kp[i].pt.y;
cout << "Point "<<i<<" Xpos = " << x <<  " Point "<<i<< " Ypos = " << y << "\n";

}    
Mat out;

    //drawKeypoints(img, kp, out, Scalar::all(255));
drawKeypoints(frame_un, kp, out, Scalar::all (255));
namedWindow("Kpts", WINDOW_FREERATIO);
    imshow("Kpts", out);
waitKey(0);
destroyWindow("Kpts");
}
   // waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of ways you can use keypoints in this manner. Are you interested in odometry or something else? I guess the generalized term is homography.

Comment: so if I used the homography technique can this coordinates be mapped to real coordinates to be operated by the manipulator

Comment: Sure. There is some discussion of that here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30502687/1531971 (and others) This question feels like it might be a bit broad, and needs more research on your part.

Answer (score 0):

Just map the coordinate system to the robot's base coordinate system and make it origin. Before doing this make sure, you have properly calibrated your vision with mm accuracy.